# Get number of times a sublist occurs in a list

Tags: python, tuples

It says that I can only have one argument using the count method. Currently I am building a game where a user input H or T and the 2 computer players randomly pick H or T for 4 rounds. I have to record the answer, which I've done, and put it to a tuple.

example:
Player 1 tossed  ['T', 'H', 'H', 'T']
Player 2 tossed  ['T', 'T', 'H', 'T']

Then I have to say how many times does the sequence (H, H) occur in each of the tuples. In the example above player 1 has one sequence of ('H', 'H') in the tuple. I have tried using the following code but it doesn't work.

```
sequence1 = player1_toss.count('H', 'H')
sequence2 = player2_toss.count('H', 'H')
print('H H found in the player 1 sequence', sequence1, 'times')
```

I keep getting the error 'builtins.TypeError: list.count() takes exactly one argument (2 given)'.
Is there anyway that I can fix this? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What you want to do is unclear, you should rework the question.

Comment: For `['H', 'H', 'H', 'T']`, the `H H` found count would be 2 or 1 times?

Comment: 2 counts @Jay. and sorry for the late response I posted the question late so I had to go to sleep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`list.count(x)`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) returns the number of times `x` occurs in a list, what you want is number of times a *sublist* pattern occurs in a list.

You can use this function -

```
def count_occurences(source, target):
    # returns no. of times target sublist occurs in source list
    count = 0
    for i in range(len(source) - len(target) + 1):
        if source[i:i+len(target)] == target:
            count += 1
    return count
```

```
>>> count_occurences(['T', 'H', 'H', 'T'], ['H', 'H'])
1
>>> count_occurences(['T', 'H', 'T', 'T'], ['H', 'H'])
0
>>> count_occurences(['H', 'H', 'H', 'T'], ['H', 'H'])
2
>>> count_occurences(['H', 'H', 'H', 'T'], ['H', 'H', 'H'])
1
```

If the sublist is big, look into some [string-matching algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String-searching_algorithm)/regexes which would be the optimal way to go about this.

Answer (score 0):

I coded a routine named `find` that will find, in a sequence, where a subsequence occurs. Since you want the count, you just find how many time the subsequence is found. All the details are worked out in the following code when you pass `all=True`. Reference to original algorithm is in the comments. This, and related routines, are [here](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/pull/11196)

```
def find(seq, subseq, start=0, all=False):
    """Return starting index at which subsequence appears in sequence
    at or beyond the index corresponding to position `start`, else -1.

    Examples
    ========

    >>> from sympy.utilities.iterables import find
    >>> find('alabaster', 'ba')
    3
    >>> find('alabaster', 'a', start=1)
    2
    >>> find('alabaster', 'e', start=-3)
    7

    To find all occurances at or past the start,
    set keyword `all` to True:

    >>> find('alabaster', 'a', all=True)
    [0, 2, 4]
    >>> find('alabaster', 'a', 1, all=True)
    [2, 4]

    See Also
    ========
    group, multiset, runs, split

    """
    # adapted from http://code.activestate.com/recipes/
    # 117223-boyer-moore-horspool-string-searching/
    from collections import defaultdict
    m = len(subseq)
    n = len(seq)
    if m > n:
        return -1 if not all else []
    if start < 0:
        start = max(-n, start) + n
    skip = defaultdict(lambda: m)
    for k in range(m - 1):
        skip[subseq[k]] = m - k - 1
    k = m - 1 + start
    loc = []
    while k < n:
        j = m - 1
        i = k
        while j >= 0 and seq[i] == subseq[j]:
            j -= 1
            i -= 1
        if j == -1:
            if all:
                loc.append(i + 1)
            else:
                return i + 1
        k += skip[seq[k]]
    return -1 if not all else loc
```

e.g. `len(find('h h h t'.split(),'h h'.split(), all=True)) -> 2`